# Exception in thread "main" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not load package CHAID; tried org.renjin.bioconductor:CHAID, org.renjin.cran:CHAID

Tags: java, r, renjin

When I am trying to run a R script in my Java web application using Renjin I am getting an exception-

> Exception in thread "main" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not
>   load package CHAID; tried org.renjin.bioconductor:CHAID,
>   org.renjin.cran:CHAID

I'am not able to find the '`CHAID`' package in Renjin website. Can anyone suggest me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is not published through [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) or [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/BiocViews.html#___Software) repositories. Currently, "only" packages from these two repositories (>14k packages) are build automatically and provided through renjin.org.

However, it is also possible to build a package locally. To do so you can follow the instructions on [Writing Renjin Extensions](http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/writing-renjin-extensions.html) pages.